# Trying to automate simple task and process control with Batch file on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to perform the following basic tasks on a Windows 7 machine. The tasks I am trying to perform are listed in order below.

1. Ask for user input for 2 numbers.
2. Search and find if a folder exists.
3. If folder does not exist, create it.
4. Search network drive for an Excel file.
5. Copy that excel file to newly created folder.
6. Open that excel file locally for editing.

My batch file code is included here. It works ok, but the user gets a list of files in a directory and then selects one to be copied. The issue I am minly having is the listed files are not correct nor complete and only shows partial directory location, not whole location with file name. I want to find all the .xls and .xlsx files in the directory. 
The directory and filename changes with no standard to the naming convention that makes searching for the correct file difficult.

This is a hack job that I have put together and my first attempt at writing a batch file, so any help, tips or changes that people have will greatly help me. I am already aware this is not good code or process, so no need to take the time to tell me. I would not be on here asking for such basic help if I knew what I was doing.

Ultimately I would like to have a standalone program to do this with a basic GUI, but do not know Python or other language well enough to accomplish the project.

Removed previous lines...

```
:FILE_COPY
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

:
:: Read in files
echo Please wait. Searching for BOM files.
for /f %%x in ('dir /s /b %filePath%\*.xls') do (
    set /a count=count+1
    set choice[!count!]=%%x
    for %%y in (!count!) do set "choice[%%y]=!choice[%%y]:%cd%\=!"
        )

echo The following files were found for PCA-%pcaNum%. 
echo Enter number of file to copy.
echo.

:
:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
     echo  %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)
echo.

:
:: Retrieve User input
set /p select=File Number: 
echo.

:
:: Print out selected filename
xcopy /v !choice[%select%]! C:\Users\dvanmeter\Desktop\CXF\%jobNum%
start !choice[%select%]!
pause
GOTO:END

:END
exit
```

I want the file list to show:

1. filename1.xlsx
2. filename2.xlsx

Instead of the list below.

1. J:......\56480\
2. J:......\56480\09763\
3. J:......\56480\Files\
4. J:......\56480\Files\
5. J:......\56480\Sales\filename.xlsx

All of those options are directories only and not files that I am looking for. Only the last one is a file but not the one I am looking for as there are more Excel files in the directories here, but they are not listed.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have found now that when the list of files is printed out, the whole directory with filename is not stored. When the print list section of code is run it shortens the path and cuts off the filename. So, when I select a file to copy it errors and says "File was not found"

What is causing the list of file locations to be cut short? Is this an inherent console limitation? I know I can get full path and filenames to display using a text file, but not sure how to implement that here.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b %filePath%\*.xls') do`

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. I will research "delims" to learn how that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b %filePath%*.xls') do - [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz)

This answer and solution was posted in a comment and not an answer so I was not able to set this as "Answered".
My issue has been fixed and my batch file is working exactly as I need it to.

Thanks for the help.